# Fall from one case to another using goto

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, switch-statement, goto

I have read multiple articles saying using goto is a massive no no in programming. But some specifically indicate that it's the abuse of goto that is wrong and that in some cases, like switch cases, it's the intended use.

So my question to you is, for future reference, which is best practice/more efficient.

this:

```
switch (a)
{
    case 1:
        //Something specific for case 1
        break;
    case 2:
        //Something specific to default and case 2
        break;
    default:
        //Something specific for default
        goto case 2;
}
```

or this:

```
switch (a)
{
    case 1:
        //Something specific for case 1
        break;
    case 2:
        //Something specific to default and case 2
        thatFunction();
        break;
    default:
        //Something specific for default
        thatFunction();
        break;
}

void thatFunction() { /*Case 2 stuff*/ }
```

**EDIT:** These two switch statements are examples, the actual code contains many more cases.

Everyone at my workplace has either never used goto or say they've only heard to never ever use it. So I came here for a definitive answer. I'm looking for an **answer** and an **explanation** or links to one.
Thanks,

Comment: I'd maybe consider goto for a state machine. Anything else I'd list the entire process in the case for one simple reason: readability. That way you never have to remember that everything you put in case 2 is also executed in the default case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a 'goto' in a switch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756084/use-a-goto-in-a-switch)

Comment: https://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always need to understand the reasoning behind any "no-no" (or "yes-yes"). That way you can understand where it makes sense to apply the rule, and where it doesn't.

The big fight against `goto` goes all the way back to programming without true procedures and functions, or even something as simple as a loop. `goto` allowed you to jump from anywhere to anywhere else, and it was extremely hard to think about what it actually means. "Don't use goto" was part of the movement to structured code, as opposed to lots of jumps all the way around the code; using things like `for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) { ... }` for iteration, rather than `if (i-- > 0) goto startLoop;`.

In a `switch`, `goto` is constrained - it can only do one thing, execute a branch of the `switch` statement. In fact, in C#, even outside of a `switch` statement, `goto` is very constrained and safe, and rarely has any of the implications that were assumed when the "Goto is evil" movement started. That doesn't mean you should start replacing all your loops with `goto`s, of course :)

Now, if things are getting this complicated, it might be that a `switch` isn't a good solution for your problem in the first place. Perhaps you can use a different structure to do what you're trying to do - there's many ways to do polymorphism and/or code reuse in C#, and one of those might be a better approach that will allow you to use clearer code to do what you're trying to do. But we can't really help you with that :)

Comment: Despite the safeness inside switch statements I still give `goto` a wary look. I'm more likely to find an alternative, such as using `bool breakEarly` inside nested loops rather than use `goto breakOutOfInnerLoop`.  It feels safer and more readable. Switch statements for fall-through only because the Thing I Want To Do Which Works In Another Language is only possible with a `goto`.

Comment: @Draco18s It's a matter of style. As far as I'm concerned, `bool breakEarly` is just a silly way to avoid `goto` for religious reasons, and a lot harder to read :P On the other hand, I'm very happy that switch statements with bodies *don't* fall-through by default. C# was designed with "make the right thing easy, and the wrong thing hard" mentality, and they actually managed to achieve that... mostly. People don't change their minds all that often - you're often stuck with what feels "normal".

Comment: Oh sure, definitely. Just saying that that's what I'm comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that logic going in circles is best kept to religion and politics.  Your `default` is really `case 2`, which means that `case 2` is really just `default`.  While it's possible that there's some execution in `case 2` that doesn't occur in `default`, it's extremely rare that you'd ever need to do anything other than an `if` condition in your `default` case.  Further, in troubleshooting the result of your `switch` evaluation cannot be immediately determined if you loop backward up the case chain. Imagine your stack trace, too.

There *are* times to use `goto`, but these are often in `exception`al cases (see what I did there) where you need to immediately execute an action (such as logging something going wrong on another thread) before `break`ing a run condition or infinite loop. The general rule with `goto` is the same as with preprocessor commands.  If there's another way you can do the same effective thing, you should use the other way for logical continuity and maintainability.

Comment: _"Your 'default' is really 'case 2', which means that 'case 2' is really just 'default'"_ - hardly, given the fact in case of `case2` the code does additional code before jumping to `default`

Comment: It didn't in the example before this post.  Still, that's addressed in the immediately following sentence.